# Multi tile rendering in cycles X

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

Just installed 3.0 and was testing out cycles for the new speed bump.

I have a 12 thread machine and it only uses one bucket/tile for rendering. I have set the size of the tile to 64x64px which is my optimal default and ticked "use tiling".

I still haven't gotten rid of version 2.92, which does the multi-tile rendering using 12 tiles simultaneously.

Below is an image of rendering in 3.0 where it uses one bucket .
This is on CPU mode, and GPU mode also gives the same one bucket result.
Is there any way to remedy this or is this a purposeful feature for speed where all power is concentrated on 1 tile?

[image: Blender 3.0 rendering]

Answer (score 4):

Disable Tiling. It no longer gives speed advantages actualy it will be slower (exept in [special cases](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html) - this one for [example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247395/cycles-x-renders-with-tiles-with-old-files-objects/247396?noredirect=1#comment420909_247396)). It is in since it can help if you run into memory Issues.

With [CyclesX](https://code.blender.org/2021/04/cycles-x/) there are [improved algorithms](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#adaptive-sampling) that decide automaticly and more fine grain where to render how mutch, and dont waste render time on already converged areas. This allows for a more [user centered approach](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#Sampling) letting you decide in genereal how noisy of an image or how mutch rendertime is okay for you - instead of fiddeling with numbers and see wat comes out and retry if it wasn't okay.