# Cycles X renders with tiles with old files/objects

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have blender 3.0 and, when I render an old project, or when I append an object from an old project, Cycles X renders with huge tiles instead of all at once (picture below). Can I change it to render all at once instead of in huge tiles?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In render settings, in the *Performance* tab, under *Memory* you will find the tile settings:

[image: Performance tab showing tile size in the Memory Settings]

You may want to read the [Performance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html) section of the manual for details, because tiles do not work the same way in 3.0 (Cycles X) as they did in 2.93 and earlier (Cycles).

The biggest difference is that the Tile size only has one dimension.  It is based on the longest dimension of your render Resolution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just unchecked "Use Tiling"

Comment: That's also the way, but rendering 2048x2048 tiles should be actually a little bit faster than rendering 3840*2160 render at once (difference depends on your scene)

Comment: @MikoCG what makes you think that?

Comment: @J.Doe in Cycles, what he says would be correct, because of how Cycles allocates GPU resources.  It would, in effect, be working on 2 tiles at once in parallel, rather than one huge tile.  I'm not sure that Cycles X is as simple, but perhaps MikoCG knows.

Comment: only based on personall testing on my 6700XT, 4000*4000px image - 1 big single tile 1:58, 4 2000*2000 tiles took 1:12 and 16 1000*1000 tiles took 1:54... 2k*2k tile seems to be faster than rendering 4k image at once

Comment: Ah thank you for testing! Actualy i now realise that this perfeclty makes sense with the note in the performance section of the manual @MartyFouts linked. For the Scene in your screenshot Tiling the scene into 4 vertical tilescould even be faster.